# Show if the Tangent line to a graph of a function is above the graph

Tags: derivatives, inequality, monotone-functions

I need some help / clarification about this problem:

> consdier the function $f(x) = x^3e^{-x^2}$. After having founf the tangent line at the point $(1, f(1))$ say if and show that $\exists p > 0$ such that the part of the graph of $f(x)$ for $x \in (1-p, 1+p)$ lies below the tangent line found earlier.

**attempts**

So the tangent line reads
$$y: g(1) + g'(1)(x-1) \longrightarrow  y: \frac{x}{e}$$

Now considering $f(x)$ given, I say $f'(x) > 0$ for $0 x < x \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ hence $f(x)$ is increasing in a neighbourhood of $x = 1/e$.

What I have to show then is that

$$\frac{x}{e} \geq f(x) \qquad \qquad x\in(1-p, 1+p)$$

That is

$$\frac{1}{e} \geq x^2e^{-x^2}$$

Calling $x^2 = t$ for $t \geq 0$ I then have to show

$$\frac{1}{e} \geq te^{-t}$$

For $t = 0$ it's obvious. Then it remains to be shown for $t > 0$

How can I proceed to prove that inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you wrote. However, the exercise can be done in the following way:

The equation of the tangent line $t$ is

$$t\colon y-f(1)=f'(1)(x-1).$$

In our case $f(1)=1/e$, and $f'(x)=3x^2e^{-x^{2}}-2x^4e^{-x^2}.$

Therefore, we have $f'(1)=1/e$, so the tangent line is

$$t\colon y=1/e(x-1)+1/e=\frac{x}{e}.$$

Our function $f$ is differentiable infinite times in a neighbourhood of $x=1$, and the last question to your problem is equivalent to ask if $f$ is concave in a neighbourhood of $x=1$. We know that this happens only if $f''(1)<0$, thus we have to show this:

$$f''(x)=6xe^{-x^2}-6x^3e^{-x^2}-8x^3e^{-x^2}+4x^5e^{-x^2} \implies f''(1)=-\frac{4}{e}<0.$$

Comment: Thank you for this. So there is no actual need to prove the existence of such $p$? The condition $f''(1) < 0$ already includes neighbourhoods of $1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If $f''(1)<0$, then there exists a neighbourhood of $x=1$ (and so such a $p$) such that $f$ is concave, or, in other words, the graph of $f$ is below the tangent line of $f$ at $x=1$.

Comment: That is clear indeed!